# What is the source code for onCreate, onStart(), onResume(), onDestroy()?

Tags: android, android-studio

The code for Oncreate() is :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // load the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.filters); 
}
```

That means there is a predefined onCreate() method. What is the code inside that method? Where can I find it?

Comment: You can install platform sources for most platform versions with the SDK manager found in Android Studio settings.

Answer (score 0):

Right/control click the `onCreate` part of `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` then select Go To --> Declaration.  If that doesn't work you may need to install the source from Preferences --> Android SDK, check Show Package Details then choose Sources for Android ## for whichever API version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the cursor above `super.onCreate` and click `ctrl` + `B` , and it will take you to the super class `FragmentActivity`